# Optimizing Group By and Date functions

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

```
SELECT p.id_product
             FROM popularity p, products pr
             WHERE p.id_product = pr.id_product
               AND p.date >= (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
               GROUP BY p.id_product order by count(p.id_product) desc LIMIT 0, 6
```

I'm wondering how to optimize my queries as much as possible. I'm trying to trim off the fat and this query in particular is giving me trouble because it is used everywhere. I have a table in which I store each instance of a product page being visited, and another table which has the products.

p.id_product is a non-unique key, whereas pr.id_product is the products' table primary key. I don't think I'm doing my query right as it seems like I'm doing a full index scan to do my join between both tables. And I'm not sure calling DATE_SUB in such a way is the best idea (I'm looking at the past month), or if my group/order is correct. My database's tables also run off InnoDB.

Is there any way I can make this faster? I've already set a limit to the query since I noticed the software never uses more than 6 results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `show create table popularity` and `show create table products` to determine your indexes already in place.

Indexes speed up performance but slow updates and inserts.

You need to find the right balance of indexes based on different ways of going after your data, so I am not one to say just pepper the tables with indexes.

Comment: The table already has a bunch of indexes. id_product in popularity is an index, and id_product in products is a primary key.

Comment: of course they are. it is the date column(s) to focus upon

Comment: I see. I added an index for both the product id and the date. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing virtually nothing with `products pr`, remove it from the query.  This will speed things up some.  (If you *do* need the table, then explain why.)

Then, adding this composite, covering, index to `popularity` will speed it up:

```
INDEX(date, id_product)
```